# Submenu in a dropdown does not work in navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple navigation that has a 'News' `<a>`. When clicked it should display a dropdown menu that has another two `<a>`'s - "Bulgaria" and "International" respectively. Clicking on the "Bulgaria" there should show up another dropdown menu with two page options - "Dunavmost" and "Petel". Clicking on the "International" should show another two page options.

The "News" `<a>` works perfectly fine, however clicking on the "Bulgaria" and "International" does not work. The code is literally the same, absolutely no reason for it to fail, however it does.

Here is my `<nav>`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">NewsWebsite</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink-News" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                News
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink-News">
                                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink-Bulgaria" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Bulgaria
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink-Bulgaria">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dunavmost</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Petel</a>
                                </div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink-International" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    International
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink-International">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">NY Times</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">DragonFire</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: The 'News' dropdown doesn't work for me..

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap doesn't support nested/inner dropdowns. Your issue now is that clicking on a nested dropdown, it will actually close the outer dropdown.

However, you can still achieve nested dropdowns with the help of a little JQuery and utilizing Bootstrap's JS methods. So here's how I did it:

**HTML**

Each inner dropdown is wrapped in a `<div class="dropdown-submenu">` container. This way we can target them later in JQuery. For the actual inner dropdown we can use the Boostrap `.dropdown-menu` classes, like you have done yourself. Also included a `tab-index` so the inner dropdown can be accessed by keyboard.

**JQuery**

[Here we take advantage of Bootstrap's dropdown methods](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/dropdowns/#methods).

When the user clicks on a `.dropdown-toggle` that is a child of a `.dropdown-submenu`, a function is fired:

```
$('.dropdown-submenu a.dropdown-toggle').on("click", function(e) { ... }
```

Inside the function we first select all inner dropdowns within the dropdown submenu's, except for the one that was clicked, and remove the show class to close them. This way we won't get any overlapping dropdown issues:

```
$('.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu').not($(this).next('.dropdown-menu')).removeClass('show');
```

Then, we toggle the show class on the submenu dropdown that was clicked:

```
$(this).next('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('show');
```

Lastly,  `e.stopPropagation();` prevents the outer dropdown from closing.

**Implementation**

Make sure you include JQuery in your `<head>`, just like the Jquery script is included on the first line of the HTML part of the snippet.

**Working example:**

```js
$('.dropdown-submenu a.dropdown-toggle').on("click", function(e) {
  $('.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu').not($(this).next('.dropdown-menu')).removeClass('show');
  $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('show');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">NewsWebsite</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink-News" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            News
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink-News">
            
            <div class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" tabindex="-1" href="#">Bulgaria</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" tabindex="-1" role="menu" aria-hidden="true">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dunavmost</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Petel</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" tabindex="-1" href="#">International</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" tabindex="-1" role="menu" aria-hidden="true">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">NY Times</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">DragonFire</a>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```